# How to when enter is hit the save button in jquery fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, jqmodal

Here is my jquery code for adding a customer record:

```
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,        //Shows dialog
    height: 300,
    width: 220,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Save": function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
          alert("Customer successfully added!");
           $.post('insertcus.php', $('#customer').serialize(), function(result){




});     

        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }



    }


});
```

How can I autoclick save button when enter is pressed?
and how can I auto refresh one field after saving?
i want to refresh my input select field.

Comment: use [.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method

Comment: what is the plugin you are actually using for the dialog that is referenced by the $("#dialog-form").dialog({...}); because jqmodal doesn't have a method like that.

Comment: as in? do i have any other option?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dialog-form").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
           $('#saveButton').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#idSaveButton').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if `#dialog-form` is a form

```
$("#dialog-form").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventdefault();
    $('#idSaveButton').trigger('click'); // or whatever the save button id might be
});
```

Actually it would be much cleaner to put the save functionality in a common callback so that both the form submit and button click events share it.

Comment: jquery button doesn't have ids

Comment: You should use the same callback for both events (the click on "Save" in your dialog and the submit of your form)